# Why overfitting is a problem for neural networks but not for models fitted through MCMC methods?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, overfitting

why for neural networks it is advised to set a test dataset apart to check if it overfitted while for statistical models fitted through mcmc this is never done?
if a model has too many parameters shouldn't it overfit with both methods?

Comment: I presume what you mean by "MCMC methods" are [Bayesian methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/265094), in which case the "guard" against overfitting [stems from the prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/344215), not from the MCMC sampling.

Comment: @Durden but no one ever set apart a test dataset for models fitted with monte carlo samplers, why?